# SQL to LINQ troubles

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have some SQL which returns two columns, the X column and Y column:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.SurveyAnswer.QuestionAnswer AS [Y], 
    COUNT(dbo.SurveyAnswer.QuestionAnswer) AS [X]
FROM  
    dbo.SurveyAnswer 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SurveyQuestion ON
        dbo.SurveyAnswer.QuestionID = dbo.SurveyQuestion.QuestionID
    INNER JOIN dbo.FieldAgentCall ON
        dbo.SurveyAnswer.JobId = dbo.FieldAgentCall.JobId AND 
        dbo.SurveyAnswer.ObjectiveId = dbo.FieldAgentCall.ObjectiveID AND
        dbo.SurveyAnswer.AgentId = dbo.FieldAgentCall.AgentID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SurveyQuestionaire ON 
        dbo.FieldAgentCall.JobId = dbo.SurveyQuestionaire.JobId and
        dbo.SurveyQuestion.QuestionaireID = dbo.SurveyQuestionaire.QuestionaireID and 
WHERE
    (dbo.SurveyQuestion.QuestionNo = 9) AND (dbo.SurveyQuestion.QuestionaireID = 1) AND  
    dbo.SurveyAnswer.QuestionAnswer <>'NA'
GROUP BY 
    dbo.SurveyAnswer.QuestionAnswer
ORDER BY 
    [Y]
```

The SQL searches through a range of tables and returns all the answers to a question and groups then, so the results would look similar to.

```
X   | Y
No  | 234
Yes | 43
```

The SQL works fine, I got that working without a problem, due to the length of the query and different parameters being sent in, the query got to an unmanageable size and decided it's time it became LINQ.

So I am trying to get the basic LINQ working to get results out, but being fairly new to LINQ, I can't quite get it working

```
var query = (from answers in db.SurveyAnswerModels.ToList()
    join question in db.SurveyQuestion.Where(i => i.QuestionID == 9 && i.QuestionaireID == 1).ToList() on answers.QuestionID equals question.QuestionID
    join questionnaire in db.SurveyQuestionnaire.ToList() on question.QuestionaireID equals questionnaire.QuestionaireID
    join fieldagent in db.FieldAgentCall.ToList() on questionnaire.JobId equals fieldagent.JobId


    group answers.QuestionAnswer by answers.QuestionAnswer into results
    select new { X = results.Count(), Y = results });
```

The result I am getting for this is the wrong amount of counts for X and the Y data isn't group

```
[{"Xs":2814,"Ys":["No","No","No","No",
```

Though it's the wrong amount because I assume I've not added the right parameters yet, so that's something I can sort, the main problem I am having though is the group by, I tried to replicate it as much as possible but failed.

The "No's" should just be a "No" with the count of how many No's there are, which it's going with the counter as it says there are 2,814 No's, I just need it to only say say "No" once.

Any advice would be great too, like where I am going wrong.

Comment: Perhaps if you have satisfactory SQL you should use ExecuteQuery<T>?

Comment: I did previously, the code is all up and running in SQL and returning the data and working and what not. However I want to remove the SQL and use LINQ, because the Stored Procedure containing the SQL has gotten to lengthy to manage

Comment: You're querying where `QuestionID = 9` in your LINQ, but your SQL queries `QuestionNo = 9`?

Comment: I understand why you might want to use LINQ and hopefully somebody will help, but the ExecuteQuery I am talking about is where you supply your *parameterised* SQL and get a result of type T. You don't need any stored procedure any more. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You'll get much more comprehensible code if you use navigation properties (like `SurveyQuestionnaire.SurveyQuestions`, if it's there) in stead of joins.

Comment: @mattytommo Yes, that is a mistake! The LINQ should be QuestionNo too

Comment: I tried to fix all the syntax errors / join issues in the SQL, hopefully it's ok now.

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. So many joins in a LINQ query would be a very ... distinct ... code smell and an indication that the joins want to become a View. Once you have a view, you can map it to an entity and apply GroupBy, OrderBy to it

Comment: Well right now, the proper SQL query is about 400 lines, which is why I moved it over, there is a lot of logic in the SQL and I am trying to move all the logic out of the Stored Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = (from answers in db.SurveyAnswerModels
    join question in db.SurveyQuestion on answers.QuestionID equals question.QuestionID
    join questionnaire in db.SurveyQuestionnaire on question.QuestionaireID equals questionnaire.QuestionaireID
    join fieldagent in db.FieldAgentCall on questionnaire.JobId equals fieldagent.JobId
    where question.QuestionID == 9 && question.QuestionaireID == 1
    group answers.QuestionAnswer by answers.QuestionAnswer into results
    select new { Count = results.Count(), Answer = results.Key });
```

Differences from yours:

1. The ToLists() are removed (this is at best unnecessary and at worst will screw up the C#-expression-to-SQL translation)
2. Moved the Where() down to the bottom (unnecessary, but makes it easier to follow)
3. Select results.Key as the answer.  Key is the the "grouped by" value for reach result group.

I think 3. is possibly the only step necessary to get it working.

Comment: This worked! So all I was missing was the .Key on the results? That's all I changed on my previous code and it worked

Comment: I suggest you *don't* use such a query. Besides being very complex, the generated SQL statements will be more complex than the initial SQL statement. Create a view to hide the multiple joins, map it  then do a simple GroupBy, OrderBy in LINQ

Comment: Well right now, the proper SQL query is about 400 lines, which is why I moved it over, there is a lot of logic in the SQL and I am trying to move all the logic out of the Stored Procedure

Comment: @JessicaPartridge  Right, #3 was the only strictly necessary move. The ToLists() are pointless and in a different context could mess you up.  In general, you only want to call ToList() when you want a (sub)query to be translated and executed right then and there.  The Linq-To-SQL  expression parser seems smart enough to ignore them in the case above.